# Google Analytics demo/sandbox account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working on a custom dashboard with React and Node that uses the Google Analytics API. I want to use a demo account to test how it works. Is there a way to achive that? I found this page but it explicitly says that it cannot be used with the API. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Google Analytics API whit Demo Account of Google Merchanding store. You have to use your own Property or create a new one and send hits with measurement protocol to populate some data.